# First order logic difference bettwen using exists and for all

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to write the following statements in first-order logic. I have been given the functions: **DirectorOf(A, B)**, **IsMovie(A)**, and **Equals(A, B)**:

1) All movies have an director.

2) No movies were directed by Mark.

---

Here is my attempt at converting the statements:

1) $ \forall \text{b}, \exists \text{a} ~ \text{(IsMovie(b)} \land \text{DirectorOf(b, a))} $

2) $ \neg \exists \text{b} ~ \text{(isMovie(b)} \land \text{DirectorOf(b, `Mark'))} $

Am I missing anything?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your (1) says that _everything in the world is a movie and was directed by someone_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm For 2 can I use say there does not exist like I have done? I know I could have done:
∀b (isMovie(b) => ¬DirectorOf(x, Mark) but I'm not sure if my current answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is correct, (1) should be:

$$∀b(IsMovie(b) → ∃a[DirectorOf(b, a)])$$

(The square brackets instead of parentheses are for readability.)

Also, there's no need to put quotation marks around the name "Mark" in (2).

Comment: Are you sure that 2 is correct?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: OK great I was marked wrong for that answer :(

Comment: It might have been because of the quotation marks I wrote about - that's the only thing wrong with the second one. Putting quotation marks around the name "Mark" kind of implies that you're talking about the four letter word "Mark" rather than Mark himself.

Comment: I was told that  could not use does not exist like I did, and I could have done ∀b (isMovie(b) => ¬DirectorOf(x, Mark). But that is saying the same thing right?

Comment: Yes, that is saying the same thing. If you need to convert between the existential and universal quantifiers, take a look at the answer by @Wuestenfux.

Comment: @QuinnXCII: That sounds like your solution was marked by someone who does not know what they're talking about, and who are just comparing naively to a particular model solution.

Comment: Thanks for you help guys I just submitted a regrade request for the 2nd question :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert via $\exists x$ equivalent to $\neg\forall x \neg$ resp. $\forall x$ equivalent to $\neg\exists x\neg$.

Comment: Is my answer for 2 correct?